# json response handling from soap wsdl

Tags: javascript, json

below is the response from **soapWSDL** in json.i need to print the pname,pjob .i can able to print "client":"http://xmlns.oracle.com/InternetMobile/AbsManagement/BPELProcessSubList", using **alert(result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse.client);** but cant able to print sublist.pname which displays undefined error

```js
{
   "Envelope":{
      "Body":{
         "processResponse":{
            "client":"http:\/\/xmlns.oracle.com\/InternetMobile\/AbsManagement\/BPELProcessSubList",
            "subList":[
               {
                  "personid":"30979",
                  "pjob":"Senior Consultant",
                  "pname":"Imad El Kustomany"
               },
               {
                  "personid":"30980",
                  "pjob":"Senior Consultant",
                  "pname":"Abdul Rahman Zaky"
               }
            ],
            "xmlns":"http:\/\/xmlns.oracle.com\/InternetMobile\/AbsManagement\/BPELProcessSubList"
         }
      },

   }
```

Comment: Try `result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse. subList[0].pname` and `result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse. subList[1].pname`. `subList`  is an array to you can loop and use index as well.

Comment: ok, let me add the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse.subList[0].pname` and `result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse.subList[1].pname`. `subList` is an array so you can loop and use index as well

Answer (score 0):

Sublist is an array so you need:

```
alert(result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse.client.subList[0].pname);
```

or if you want to display pnames of all items

```
result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse.client.subList.forEach(function(el){
    alert(el.pname);
});
```